# Force reload of index

Tags: ember.js

My application has a `nodes` pool, and several sub-nodes (`queues`, `services`, ...). I need to constantly access the `nodes` pool, and I need to make sure that the data is up-to-date with the data in the backend. The data in the backend can change due to several reasons, for example:

1. side effects of working with other objects: the backend will modify not only the affected object, but related objects too. For example, an update of a service document could affect a queue. This is done in the backend, and the ember application is not aware of this.
2. Maybe another user has modified objects in the backend, and I want to get a fresh copy.

Usually the objects are loaded when accessing the route `#/nodes/index`, but sometimes I would like to force a refresh of the store, without hoping that the user performs an access to the right route. How can I trigger this programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ember data you can reload the data using. `recordArray.update()`, and using  `window.setInterval` to schedule to your desired time. A `RecordArray` instance is get when the `Model.find()` is resolved.

```
Model.find().then(function(recordArray) {
});
```

The easy way to do this is in the ember way, is returning your data in the `model` hook, and getting the recordArray instance in `afterModel` hook. So use this instance to perform an `update` at some specific time using `setInverval`, by example:

```
App.NodesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Nodes.find();
  },
  afterModel: function(recordArray) {
    setInterval(function() {
      recordArray.update();
    }, 1000); //each second
  }
});
```

Just be aware with the transition to nodes index route, because every time will be created a new  `setInterval`, and things will load n times more to each transition to that route.

To fix this, store the id returned of `setInterval`, and use the `clearInterval` to remove the previous task:

```
afterModel: function() {
    if (this.get('jobId')) {
      clearInterval(jobId);
    }
    var jobId = setInterval(function() {
      record.update()
    }, 1000); // each second
    this.set('jobId', jobId);
}
```

I have created a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/S2m4G/).

Comment: Thanks, I am going to implement this in my application. Something still not clear to me is, how can I do this if the `NodesIndexRoute` is never accessed? I still need the nodes for the other parts of the applications to work. Maybe I need to trigger this on the `ApplicationRoute` ...

Comment: I have used the `NodesIndexRoute` as sample, because this is the common place where the list of records is showed. If you want to start this without care about routing, maybe when app starts, `ApplicationRoute` would be the place.